# How to Synchronize angular 2 or 4 life cycle hook and observables

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I want to Synchronize my angular 2 life cycle hooks with Observable. For Example in the below Scenario.

```
**Temp Component**

    @Component({
    selector: 'temp-component',
    template: `<table [tableData]='tableData'>
    </table >`
})

export class TempComponent implements OnInit{
private data;
private tabledata;
   ngOnInit {
       this.getData(Dataurl).subscribe(
                        (data3: any) => {
                            this.data = data3;
                        },
                        (err: any) => {
                            console.error(err);
                        },
                        () => {
                            this.tabledata = this.data;
                            console.log('In temp component..', this.tabledata);
                        }

   }

getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(err.json().error));
    }

}

**Table Component :**

@Component({
    selector: 'table',
    template: `code for displaying table`
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
   @Input tableData: any;
   ngOnInit{
      console.log('table Data..' , this.tableData);
   }
}


**Output :**
table Data.. undefined
In temp component.. (Displaying table data info)
```

In the above scenario I want the table data to be displayed as same as in temp component. Can anyone has any idea on how to make the table to displayed once the observable completes.

Comment: Push the value to a shared service and then subscribe to that.

Comment: Your code will work just fine. but the misunderstanding that on init the component the observable may not finished yet so the console gave you undefined. On the other hand the second console will happened only on observable complete event. so the data will pass correctly and try to use *ngFor in your table component once the "tableData" is not undefined and you will see that it will work !

Comment: Yes @Nour , Once the Observables completed in this component I have to detect that table data is undefined for that I used ngOnchange it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ngOnChange hook, Angular call this method when the component's input value change. I mean:

```
.....
export class TableComponent implements OnChanges {
@Input() tableData:any;
ngOnChanges(changes:SimplesChanges){
      if(changes['tableData']){
           console.log(this.tableData);
      }
}
```

hope can help!!!

Comment: This works Absolutely fine but my output is like                                       
 table Data..undefined                                                                                                             table Data..{some data}

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code except you're not actually displaying the data, and you get the wrong idea from what your console logs are telling you, just as Nour notes in the comments.

You can see this if you make your input variable a property with a setter instead.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table',
  template: `<code>{{ tableData | json }}</code>`
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() public set tableData(value: any) {
    console.log('table data updated: ', value);
    this._tableData = value;
  }

  public get tableData() {
    return this._tableData;
  }
  private _tableData: any;

  ngOnInit{
    console.log('table Data..' , this.tableData);
  }
}
```

You should now see your

> table Data..undefined

as before, followed up by the

> table data updated: {}

text when the value is updated. Try to display the data in your template, for instance using

```
<code>{{ tableData | json ]]</code>
```

too see in your view when the value is updated. Also don't forget that values that you bind to should be `public` in order for aot-compiling to work if that's a feature you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, This is a new approach for me , let me try it and let you know.